# Angular2 Click method always return false value

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, angular2-forms, angular2-services

I have four input fields which need to validated at the backend. So i have written one service call and based on output i need to add class to the input field. So if OK then green else red.

I want to use same method for all as backend validation is same. So i am trying to return boolean value from the on click function but it always returning false. Here is my code:-

```
  <div class="row"><div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-2 nopadding"><div class="form-group   pull-right"><label>Query1:</label></div></div><div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-0"><div class="form-group input-group"><input type="text" [ngClass]="{red: !(query1ok),green: (query1ok)}" class="form-control" name="query1" id="query1" [(ngModel)]="sampledetails.rules[0].query1"><span class="input-group-btn"><a  href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-default" alt="validate query" (click)="[query1ok]:validateQuery(query1ok,sampledetails.rules[0].query1)" type="button"><i class="fa fa-play"></i></a></span></div></div></div> <div class="row"><div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-2 nopadding"><div class="form-group   pull-right"><label>Query2:</label></div></div><div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-0"><div class="form-group input-group"><input type="text" [ngClass]="{red: !(query2ok),green: (query2ok)}" class="form-control" name="query2" id="query2" [(ngModel)]="sampledetails.rules[0].query2"><span class="input-group-btn"><a  href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-default" alt="validate query" (click)="validateQuery(query2ok,samplerdetails.rules[0].query2)" type="button"><i class="fa fa-play"></i></a></span></div></div></div><div class="row"><div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-2 nopadding"><div class="form-group   pull-right"><label>Query3:</label></div></div><div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-0"><div class="form-group input-group"><input type="text" [ngClass]="{red: !(query3ok),green: (query3ok)}" class="form-control" name="query3" id="query3" [(ngModel)]="samplerdetails.rules[0].query3"><span class="input-group-btn"><a  href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-default" alt="validate query" (click)="validateQuery(query3ok,ssampledetails.rules[0].query3)" type="button"><i class="fa fa-play"></i></a></span></div></div></div><div class="row"><div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-2 nopadding"><div class="form-group   pull-right"><label>Query4:</label></div></div><div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-0"><div class="form-group input-group"><input type="text" [ngClass]="{red: !(query4ok),green: (query4ok)}" class="form-control" name="query4" id="query4" [(ngModel)]="samplerdetails.rules[0].query4"><span class="input-group-btn"><a  href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-default" alt="validate query" (click)="validateQuery(query4ok,sampledetails.rules[0].query4)" type="button"><i class="fa fa-play"></i></a></span></div></div></div>


validateQuery(querystatus, query){
    this._validatorService.validateQuery(query).subscribe(
            (data) => {
                 return false;
            },
            (err) =>{
            return true;
            }
        );
    }
```

So want to know if its possible to return boolean from click function in angular2 and if yes, then how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be returning the subscribed data as below

```
validateQuery(querystatus, query){
    this._validatorService.validateQuery(query).subscribe(
            (data) => {
                 return data;//////////////////////////
            },
            (err) =>{
            return true;
            }
        );
    }
```

Update 1

```
validateQuery(querystatus, query){
    this._validatorService.validateQuery(query).subscribe(
            (data) => {
                 this.queryok= false;
            },
            (err) =>{
                 this.queryok= true;
            }
        );
    }
```

You function call in HTML will be as

```
(click)="validateQuery(query1ok,sampledetails.rules[0].query1)"
```

Comment: I tried this way. same error. I want to return false when its in err else data which is returning boolean. My data is returing true but still I am getting false in click method. Just want to check if I am assign return value correctly? here is my code:- **'(click)="query1ok=validateQuery(query1ok,sampledetails.rules[0].query1)"**

Comment: are  u available in team viewer? `query1ok` what it means?

Comment: Sorry no access to team viewer. query1ok  is a variable i have declared in  in my class like **query1ok: boolean= true;** and its the same variable i am using for condition in ngClass

Comment: Yeah that will work but here quer1ok is hardcoded. I want to pass it in parameter and use it as I have 4 diff fields that need to validated and i want to use same function for all. Please check my updated code.

Comment: r u using `*ngFor`

Comment: No. My Html is hardcoded. My requirement is to give user four input fields where he can add 4 diff queries and each need to validated at backend and each input field should be separately high lighted based on that particular validation. I can use separate function but i don't want same code to be repeated again and again. So was wondering if I can pass n class variable in click method and if I can modify its value in validatequery function.

Comment: in that case make the `queryok` variable to be an `array`

Comment: thanks Aravind. It worked. I used array for storing responses and highlighting input based on response. Thanks a lot..

Comment: Thank you. delete the useless comments